# Example of bounded function in $L^1[a,b]$ but not in $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Can you give me an example of a bounded function $f\in L^1[a,b]$ which $f\not\in L^2[a,b]$?

Thank you

Comment: Every bounded function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ belongs to both $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Comment: If $|f|\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ (i.e. bounded), then $f\in L^{2}[a,b]$ since $\int_{[a,b]}|f(x)|^{2}dx \leq M^2(b-a)<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible since $$\int_{[a,b]}{|f(x)|^{2} \, d\lambda(x) } \leq M_{f}\int_{[a,b]}{|f(x)| \, d\lambda(x)} < \infty$$

Where $M_{f}>0$ is a bound of $f$

Moreover $$L^{\infty}[a,b] \subset L^{2}[a,b]$$

Comment: Of course! thanks!